# Can't we just use PCA to solve the problem of Linear Regression

Tags: statistics, machine-learning

From my intuitive understanding till now
If I have let's say a set of 2D points, then performing the PCA will give me the direction that reduces the variance along one direction drastically right. But isn't this also the purpose of Linear Regression. To basically reduce the distance of the points from the line. 
PCA vs Linear Regression Image

[image]

Comment: PCA and linear regression are minimizing different objective functions and there’s no reason to expect them to find the same line. Indeed, they will usually find different lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In linear regression, we assume that there is no error in the $x$-direction.

In linear regression, the errors are the vertical distance to the line squared and not the closest distance to the point.

Comment: True, But they will still give the same line, right? 
1. Assumption no error in the x-direction
A. this is a valid point, but I am not able to gauge its effect on the resultant line that both methods will give us
2. Errors are vertical distance to the line
the error function more or less remains the same because the vertical distance to the line would just be d/cos(theta) where d is the closest distance between the point and line and theta is the angle the line makes with the x-axis.

Comment: [here](https://shankarmsy.github.io/posts/pca-vs-lr.html) is a visualization.

Comment: thanks for the visualisation, I think I now better understand the point you were making initially. So if I interpreted correctly, can we say PCA line would usually be in between both those regression lines, because y~x is about minimizing vertical distances and x~y is about minimizing horizontal distances, and PCA is about minimizing the hypotenuse that is the sqrt(v_dist^2+h_dist^2).